# Django: How to set a property in a model using @property

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to *assign* two properties to my **User** class. The first assigned property will be used in assigning the second property. Is this correct? I'm using the `@property` decorator...

```
class User(n):

    group = models.ForeignKey(Brand, null=True, blank=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    # assign the apps property (User.apps)
    @property
    def assign_apps(self):
        self.apps = get_user_apps(self.group, self.is_admin)

    # with User.apps, assign the apps_meta property (User.apps_meta)
    @property
    def assign_apps_meta(self):
        self.apps_meta = get_user_apps_meta(self.apps)
```

Comment: Argh, this code doesn't make any sense at all. Why would you use `@property` to assign a value from another method? How would you call it? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm basically just trying to assign self.apps (User.apps) and then use self.apps to assign self.apps_meta (User.apps_meta)

Comment: Yes but why do you want to use a property to do either of those?

Comment: I thought I needed the @property decorator to assign a property to a model. I modified my question to what I think is correct.

Answer (score 3):

I still don't understand why you want to use properties here. This really isn't what they are for. The property decorator is for creating getters and setters for complex attributes; that's not what you're doing at all.

This seems like a job for a simple method.

```
def assign_apps(self):
    self.apps = get_user_apps(self.group, self.is_admin)
    self.apps_meta = get_user_apps_meta(self.apps)
```

and now you can call `my_user.assign_apps()`.

Answer (score 0):

if you're writing method that returns some value or string then you should use

```
@property decorator
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    birth_date = models.DateField()

    @property
    def age(self):
        return ......
```